# Why do I sometimes pronounce my th's as f's and v's?

Tags: pronunciation, accent

I am essentially a native speaker. My family moved to the US when I was ~4 and even before then spoke to me in English quite a lot in preparation. My family is Ashkenazi Jewish and I used to speak Russian and Hebrew as a young child (~3-5 years old). I grew up in the Boston Metro area. People sometimes bring up how I occasionally pronounce my th's wrong such as when I say "three" as "free". Is this just a personal quirk or may it be connected to my linguistic influences?

Comment: Sharing what words you do this in might help contextualize this. See [Wiki _th-fronting_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-fronting).

Comment: It is called [th-fronting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-fronting) and is not uncommon in certain groups.  I live in *Rotherhithe* in SE London and centuries ago people like Samuel Pepys and John Evelyn and Jonathan Swift seemed to have pronounced the second *th* with an *f*  so much so that they wrote it as *Redriffe*.

Comment: Do other members of your family do this? Th-fronting is rare in most of the US but common in the UK.

Comment: Also: a question. Do you also do this in words like *this,* where a voiced *th* occurs at the start of a word, making it sound like *vis*?

Comment: So you Brits are the reason why Siri types "with" when I dictate the word "whiff". Or is AAVE the reason?

Answer (score 4):

As [Wikipedia explains,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-fronting) this pronunciation is called *th-fronting.* It involves pronouncing /θ/ and /ð/, the *th* sounds in *death* and *clothe*, as [f] and [v], respectively, making those words sound like *deaf* and *clove.*

As Geoff Lindsey explains *th-fronting* has become quite common in British English (*English after RP,* p. 76):

> TH-fronting is becoming considerably more widespread. It can be heard across Britain, from speakers in all educational and socio-economic groups, mainly from the young but also from some in middle age. It’s occasionally heard, in some words at least, from television presenters, including some in TV news. [...] It’s remarkable that this change has spread rapidly both in geographical and social terms. It seems likely that its use will increase, and some pronunciations with replacements of /θ/ and /ð/ may become established as standard. It’s even conceivable, in the more distant future, that /θ/ and /ð/ will become endangered sounds in Britain.

But it's quite rare in American English; Wikipedia notes that it can occur in [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English), but there *th-stopping,* pronouncing those sounds as [t] and [d], is more common.

So why would you use it? Geoff Lindsey makes another remark that is likely relevant:

> [The sounds [θ] and [ð]] are relatively rare in the world’s languages, and they’re among the last sounds to be acquired by native-speaking children. This suggests that they’re intrinsically rather tricky articulations. Most non-natives find them challenging.

If you learned English at least partly from non-native speakers, and didn't fully acquire these sounds in childhood, it's quite reasonable that you'd end up replacing them with other sounds--in this case, [f] and [v]--instead.

Comment: +1 Nice post! Worth mentioning that for these reasons /f/ and /v/ are by far and away the best substitutes for the dental fricatives in UK English if a learner finds them difficult. Far, far better than /s/ and /z/!